# Endomorphism of a rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, noetherian, ring-isomorphism, morphism

I was trying to prove that a surjective Endomorphism $f:A \to A$ of a noetherian ring is also injective. I would like to know why this argument is not correct?
$A/\rm{Ker}f \cong \rm{Im}f=A \Rightarrow Kerf=\{0\}$

Comment: a priori, we cannot deduce from $A\simeq A/I$ that $I\simeq 0$. The problem is we don't know what the isomorphism is. If however the isomorphism happens to be the canonical projection then yes, $I$ is $0$.
Anyway, I'm looking for a counter-example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your argument cannot be correct, since it doesn't use the noetherian hypothesis; this is because for a non-noetherian ring the statement is wrong:
Consider the polynomial ring $A = \mathbb Z[x_1,x_2,x_3,\dotsc]$ in infinitely many variables. It is clearly not noetherian. Now, consider the ring homomorphism $f\colon A\to A$ given on variables by $f(x_1) = 0$ and $f(x_n) = x_{n-1}$ for $n>1$. 
It is surjective, but not injective.

Comment: So can't I use the isomorphism theorem in every case?

Comment: The isomorphism theorem still holds, but the implication is wrong. See Leaning’s comment under your post.

Comment: Great example. I thought of $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}([0,1],\mathbb{R})\rightarrow \mathcal{C}^{\infty}([0,1],\mathbb{R})$ given by the differential $f\rightarrow f'$. It's basically the same idea.

Comment: Thank you so much guys!!

Comment: @Leaning I like your example, since it appears in nature. Thank you for sharing!

Comment: On the contrary, $f\rightarrow f'$ is not a ring endomorphism... It's a bit far from being the correct one :D.

Comment: Oh... I had not considered that. Too bad :(

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't work because there isn't any general principle of ring theory according to which $R/I$ should be isomorphic to $R$ only if $I=0$.

If $f$ were surjective but not injective, then the sequence of ideals $$0\subseteq\ker( f)\subseteq \ker (f^2)\subseteq \ker (f^3)\subseteq\cdots$$ would be *strictly* increasing, which is inconsistent with noetherianity of $A$.

Comment: I think this should be the accepted answer

Comment: @Javi I don't: I have not done a great job at answering the actual question.

Comment: @Gae.S. How can you be sure that the sequence doesn’t already terminate?

Comment: @cansomeonehelpmeout It's a set-theoretic fact that for a function $g:A\to B$ and any two subsets $S_1,S_2\subseteq B$, the condition $g^{-1}[S_1]=g^{-1}[S_2]$ holds if and only if $S_1\cap g[A]=S_2\cap g[A]$. With $g=f^n$, $S_1=0$ and $S_2=\ker f$ you obtain $\ker f^n\ne \ker f^{n+1}$.